# Como colocar trecho Html em todos os elementos filhos menos no último?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Tenho uma tabela gerada dinamicamente, e quero colocar um `input` dentro de cada `td`. Eu consigo pegar o id do `tr`, então eu faço:

```
$("#id").children().html("<input type='text' value='" + valor + "' />");
```

Assim ele coloca um `input` dentro de cada `td` daquele `tr`, mas eu não quero que ele coloque o `input` no ultimo `td`, como posso fazer isso?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use o operador [.not()](http://api.jquery.com/not/) combinado com o seletor [:last-child](https://api.jquery.com/last-child-selector/)

```
$("#id").children().not(":last-child").html("<input type='text' value='" + valor + "' />");
```

Answer (score 6):

Podes usar [como o Pedro sugeriu](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/107871/129), podes ainda usar `.not(":last")`:

#### jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9pzyfuro/1/

---

Eu costumo juntar `.slice(0, -1)` ao seletor para retirar o ultimo elemento dessa seleção:

```
$("#id").children().slice(0, -1).html("<input type='text' value='" + valor + "' />");
```

#### jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9pzyfuro/

Answer (score 3):

A função children pode receber como parametro um seletor, e neste seletor você pode utilizar diretamente o :not como também o :last.

```
$("#id").children(":not(:last)").html("<input type='text' value='" + valor + "' />");
```

Exemplo: http://codepen.io/silviolucenajunior/pen/ZQyNjx